# how to add class and icon in route link Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-routing

I have a route-link vuejs :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { user: 123 }}">view</router-link>
```

I want to add class : `class="btn btn-primary"` and **icon** in that route-link. Please give me ideas. Thanks

Comment: do you use any UI library like vuetify or bootstrap-vue?

Answer (score 1):

Vue-router's router link just add a-href link with matching link and add some router-exact classes so you can just add classes to router-link and it will work. Same as html inside.
`<router-link class="btn btn-primary" :to="{ name: 'user', params: { user: 123 }}"><i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>view</router-link>`

Answer (score 0):

You could add [`tag`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#tag) prop with `button` as value and your icon next to the router link text:

```
<router-link tag="button" class="btn btn-primary" :to="{ name: 'user', params: { user: 123 }}">
  <icon name="someName"/>   
   view
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, in my case I am working on a dashboard with Tailwind and vue 3, I was able to add an icon from https://heroicons.com/

1 copy icon select in heroicons
2 Pastes en router componet

```
     <--here paste icon copy here-->

    <span class="text-white">Acerca de</span>


    </router-link>
```

Comment: seems unrelated to the question about router-link